# Cut seconds in DateTime field in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have date and time in my sql serverdata base in this format:

> 2018-05-18 13:14:59.9277026

But when i use SSSRS reporting services and format that datetime field like

> dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm

i loss seconds but SSRS round time and i get one more minute in report

Result in report is

> 2018-05-18 13:15

which is not ok for me.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I will round off if you use dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this format expression

```
 =CDate(Fields!data.Value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I add this as field expression and removed my formatting for that field in Format